# Unfortunately Facebook Friends List has stopped

Tags: android, android-emulator

i have made an app in which i am fetching list of all my Facebook friends, but now i have decided to add Tab functionality in my application, but whenever i run my app getting error message :

```
 Unfortunately Facebook Friends List has stopped
```

*Logcat Says:*

```
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.chr.tatu.sample.friendslist/com.chr.tatu.sample.friendslist.TabSample}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.chr.tatu.sample.friendslist/com.chr.tatu.sample.friendslist.FriendsList}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.chr.tatu.sample.friendslist/com.chr.tatu.sample.friendslist.FriendsList}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2023)
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:749)
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:240)
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at com.chr.tatu.sample.friendslist.TabSample.addTab(TabSample.java:50)
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at com.chr.tatu.sample.friendslist.TabSample.setTabs(TabSample.java:29)
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at com.chr.tatu.sample.friendslist.TabSample.onCreate(TabSample.java:25)
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  ... 11 more
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at com.chr.tatu.sample.friendslist.FriendsList.init(FriendsList.java:98)
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at com.chr.tatu.sample.friendslist.FriendsList.onCreate(FriendsList.java:57)
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-15 11:34:23.526: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  ... 23 more
```

*TabSample.java:*

```
 public class TabSample extends TabActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabmain);
    setTabs() ;
}
private void setTabs()
{
    addTab("All", R.drawable.tab_menu, FriendsList.class);
    addTab("Current Month", R.drawable.tab_offers, FriendsList.class);

    addTab("Current Week", R.drawable.tab_location, FriendsList.class);
    addTab("Today", R.drawable.tab_reservation, FriendsList.class);
}

private void addTab(String labelId, int drawableId, Class<?> c)
{
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId); 

    View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);
    TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(labelId);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    icon.setImageResource(drawableId);

    spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
    spec.setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
}
  }
```

*FriendsList.java:*

```
    public class FriendsList extends Activity  implements FacebookRequest, OnItemClickListener {
private static String LOG_TAG = "FriendsList";
private static JSONArray jsonArray;
private static ListView friendsList;
private Handler mHandler;
  private Button saveGreeting;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mHandler = new Handler();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    try {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        getActionBar().hide();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    setContentView(R.layout.friends_list_screen);
    try {
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
        } catch (Exception e) {}

    init();

    saveGreeting = (Button) findViewById(R.id.greeting);
    saveGreeting.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        customGreeting(v);
        }
    });
}

public void customGreeting(View v) {
    Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://google.com/"));
    startActivity(myWebLink);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy(); 
    exit();
}

private void exit() {
    if (friendsList != null)
        friendsList.setAdapter(null);
    friendsList = null;
    jsonArray = null;
    GetProfilePictures.clear();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
    exit();
}



private void init() {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String response = extras.getString("FRIENDS");
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate()" + response);

        try {
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            FacebookUtility.displayMessageBox(this, this.getString(R.string.json_failed));
        }

        friendsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.friends_list);
        friendsList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        friendsList.setAdapter(new FriendListAdapter(this));
        friendsList.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        // Removing the delimiters between the items. It looks prettier 
        friendsList.setDivider(null); 
        friendsList.setDividerHeight(0);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreateOptionsMenu()"); 
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
/**
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onOptionsItemSelected()");
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_refresh:
            FacebookUtility.logout(this);
            setProgressBarInDVisibility(true);
            return true;
        case R.id.retry_button:
        GetProfilePictures.clear();
        init();
        return true;                
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); 

    }
}
**/

public void onRequestReceived(int result, String message) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onRequestReceived(" + result + ")");
    if(isFinishing())
        return;
   //   setProgressBarInDVisibility(false);
    switch (result) {
    case FacebookRequest.COMPLETED:
        FacebookUtility.clearSession(this);
        finish();
        break;
    case FacebookRequest.IO_EXCEPTION:
    case FacebookRequest.FILE_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION:
    case FacebookRequest.MALFORMED_URL_EXCEPTION:
    case FacebookRequest.FACEBOOK_ERROR:
        FacebookUtility.displayMessageBox(this, this.getString(R.string.logout_failed));
        break;
    }
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
//  Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onItemClick()");

     try {
            final long friendId;
            friendId = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getLong("uid");
            String name = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("name");
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle(R.string.post_on_wall_title)
                    .setMessage(String.format(getString(R.string.post_on_wall), name))
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Bundle params = new Bundle();

                            params.putString("to", String.valueOf(friendId));
                            params.putString("caption", getString(R.string.app_name));
                            params.putString("description", getString(R.string.app_desc));
                            params.putString("picture", FacebookUtility.HACK_ICON_URL);
                            params.putString("name", getString(R.string.app_action));
                            FacebookUtility.facebook.dialog(FriendsList.this, "feed", params,
                                    (DialogListener) new PostDialogListener());
                        }

                    }).setNegativeButton(R.string.no, null).show();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            showToast("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /*
* Callback after the message has been posted on friend's wall.
*/
    public class PostDialogListener extends BaseDialogListener {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
            if (postId != null) {
                showToast("Message posted on the wall.");
            } else {
                showToast("No message posted on the wall.");
            }
        }
    }

    public void showToast(final String msg) {

        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(FriendsList.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
    }


public class FriendListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SectionIndexer {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private GetProfilePictures picturesGatherer = null;
    FriendsList friendsList;
    private String[] sections;

    Hashtable<Integer, FriendItem> listofshit = null;

    public FriendListAdapter(FriendsList friendsList) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "FriendListAdapter()");
        this.friendsList = friendsList;
        sections = new String[getCount()];
        listofshit = new Hashtable<Integer, FriendItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < getCount(); i++) {
            try {

                sections[i] = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name").substring(0);
                sections[i] = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("birthday").substring(1);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                sections[i] = "";
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "getJSONObject: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        if (picturesGatherer == null) {
            picturesGatherer = new GetProfilePictures();
        }
        picturesGatherer.setAdapterForListener(this);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(friendsList.getBaseContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "getCount()");
        if (jsonArray == null)
            return 0;
        return jsonArray.length();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "getItem()");
        return listofshit.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "getItemId()");
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "getView(" + position + ")");

        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        try {
            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "getJSONObject: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        FriendItem friendItem;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_friend, null);
            friendItem = new FriendItem();

            convertView.setTag(friendItem);
        }
        else {
            friendItem = (FriendItem) convertView.getTag();
        }

        friendItem.friendPicture = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.picture_square);
        friendItem.friendName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        friendItem.friendDob = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dob);
        friendItem.friendLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.friend_item);

        try {
            String uid = jsonObject.getString("uid");
            String url = jsonObject.getString("pic_square");
            friendItem.friendPicture.setImageBitmap(picturesGatherer.getPicture(uid, url));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "getJSONObject: " + e.getMessage());
            friendItem.friendName.setText("");
            friendItem.friendDob.setText("");
        }

        try {
            friendItem.friendName.setText(jsonObject.getString("name"));
            friendItem.friendDob.setText(jsonObject.getString("birthday"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "getJSONObject: " + e.getMessage());
            friendItem.friendName.setText("");
            friendItem.friendDob.setText("");
        }

        listofshit.put(position, friendItem);

        return convertView;
    }

    public int getPositionForSection(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public Object[] getSections() {
        return sections;
    }
}

class FriendItem {
    TextView friendDob;
    int id;
    ImageView friendPicture;
    TextView friendName;
    RelativeLayout friendLayout;

}
}
```

Comment: check Bundle values, you cannot pass bundle values.

Comment: It says in your Logcat output, _NULLPointer at FriendsList.java:98_. What's at line number 98?

Comment: @varevarao the 98th line is: String response = extras.getString("FRIENDS");

Comment: Try using [getIntent().getStringExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra(java.lang.String)), in place of getting a Bundle and then the String extra.

Comment: @rajeshwaran yes you are right, i have deleted these two lines: Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
         String response = extras.getString("FRIENDS"); and now i am getting tab, but not getting list of my friends why dude?

Comment: @Liza pass bundle values in TabSample class.

Comment: You're using your TabSample class to launch the FriendList activity, but not passing any extras in that call. I'm not sure how you want to implement this, but you could store the friends in a separate static class, or as @rajeshwaran says, pass the extras to TabClass and THEN to the FriendList activity.

Comment: @varevarao i agree with you and rajeshwaran, i have tried to write these two lines in TabSample class but still i am not getting list of FB Friends ....plz tell me where i am doing mistake, and i have posted complete code of TabSample and FriendsList Class please tell me what code need to move and where bcoz i have tried but not getting list...

Comment: @rajeshwaran  have tried to write these two lines in TabSample class but still i am not getting list of FB Friends ....plz tell me where i am doing mistake, and i have posted complete code of TabSample and FriendsList Class please tell me what code need to move and where bcoz i have tried but not getting list...

Comment: intent.putExtra("FRIENDS", values); add this line, in your addTab() method in TabSample class.